# Tick marks for datelistplot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, ticks

I have this data and I want to plot it with six dates on the x-axis.  The first tick should be the first data points date minus two days and the last tick should be the last data points date plus two days.  New information may be entered so I cannot explicitly set the tick marks I want.  They must be recalculated every time a new plot is generated.

Thank you

```
data = {{DateObject[{2021, 1, 21}], 201.8},
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 22}], 203.6}, 
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 25}], 202.5},
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 26}], 201.4},
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 27}], 201.1},
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 29}], 201.6},
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 30}], 201.1},
   {DateObject[{2021, 1, 31}], 200.7},
   {DateObject[{2021, 2, 1}], 200.1}};
DateListPlot[data, Joined -> False, LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}, DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Day"}]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can control the ticks explicitly with `FrameTicks`, but don't forget to adjust the `PlotRange`. Date algebra can be performed with `DatePlus`.

```
minmax = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
min = DatePlus[minmax[[1]], -2];
max = DatePlus[minmax[[2]], 2];

DateListPlot[data, Joined -> False, LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{min, max}, Automatic},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {DateRange[min, max], None}},
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Day"}]
```

[image: DateListPlot]

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {{DateObject[{2021, 1, 21}], 
    201.8}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 22}], 
    203.6}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 25}], 
    202.5}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 26}], 
    201.4}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 27}], 
    201.1}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 29}], 
    201.6}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 30}], 
    201.1}, {DateObject[{2021, 1, 31}], 
    200.7}, {DateObject[{2021, 2, 1}], 200.1}};

incr = (QuantityMagnitude[
      DateDifference[data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]]] + 4)/5;

ticks = DateRange[DatePlus[data[[1, 1]], -2], 
   DatePlus[data[[-1, 1]], 2], incr];

DateListPlot[data,
 PlotRange -> {{ticks[[1]], ticks[[-1]]}, Automatic},
 Joined -> False,
 LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {ticks, None}},
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Day"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[ticks, prange, n]
prange = DateBounds[data[[All, 1]]] + Quantity[#, "Days"] &@{-2, 2}
ticks[n_] := DateRange[Splice@prange, n]

DateListPlot[data
 , Joined -> False, LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}
 , DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Day"}
 , PlotRange -> {prange, Automatic}
 , FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks[3], None}}
 , GridLines -> {ticks[1], Automatic}
 ]
```

[image]